# Django save() method does not insert data to my Mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have tried to entered data to Mysql database using Django. The user enters the required data through addSubscriber.html page to save in the database but the data entered is not saved in the database. Whenever I check the Mysql table (in this case 'Subscribers' table), the table is empty. Should I install mysql-connecter or not?

Here are my files:
views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views import generic
from .models import Subscribers
from .forms import addSubsForm



@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    context = {'user': user}
    template = 'dashboard.html'
    return render(request, template, context)



@login_required
def addSubscriber(request):
    template = 'addSubscriber.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = addSubsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                name = form.cleaned_data['name']
                area = form.cleaned_data['area']
                phoneNumber = form.cleaned_data['phoneNumber']
                installationCost = form.cleaned_data['installationCost']
                billNumber = form.cleaned_data['billNumber']
                print name
                Subs = Subscribers.objects.create(name=name, area=area, phoneNumber=phoneNumber, installationCost=installationCost, billNumber=billNumber)
                Subs.save()
                return redirect('report')

    else:
            form = addSubsForm()

    return render(request, template, {'form': form})




@login_required
def report(request):
    context = locals()
    template = 'report.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class Subscribers(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    installationCost = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    billNumber = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

addSubscriber.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}



<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-7">

{% if form %}
<br>


      <form class="POST" action="." method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}

         {{ form|crispy }}
            <input type="submit" value="submit form" class="btn btn-primary"/>



      </form>

{% endif %}
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from dashboard import views as dashboard_views
from profiles import views as profiles_views

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', profiles_views.home, name='homepage'),
    url(r'^contact/$', profiles_views.contact, name='contact'),
    url(r'^dashboard/$', dashboard_views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^dashboard/addSubscriber/$', dashboard_views.addSubscriber, name='addSubscriber'),
    url(r'^dashboard/userDetail/$', dashboard_views.userDetail, name='userDetail'),
    url(r'^dashboard/report/$', dashboard_views.report, name='report'),


    url(r'^account/', include('allauth.urls')),

]

# this statement says that: if in the settings file, DEBUG is true than use this static URL
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you post the `DATABASES` setting here?

Comment: the call to `Subs.save()` is probably obsolete since objects.create saves the the object itself. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you dont need all this extra things in the view as you are using form and why use `create` and also `save`??

just try this inside the `form.is_valid`

```
       if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            f.save(using='db2')
            return redirect('report')
```

Comment: If I don't use 'form.cleaned_data' wont it save the encrypted form of data I entered?

Comment: yes it will, just try it once and let me know what you see

Comment: The same error is displayed. I tried the solution given by @Arun and I have posted the error I get after applying it. Please see it.

Comment: use the solution and remove the unique=True from the billnumber field and makemigrations first then migrate.

Comment: I just removed the unique=True and applied makemigrations and migrate but whenever I use python manage.py migrate, the error is the same

Comment: yes the problem is because you already have some data, so you need to recreate your database by dropping it, then delete all the migration files from migrations folder except init.py. then run migrate,makemigration,migrate. then try to add data from the form and check

Comment: I dropped the database and created a new one named 'Subscribers'. Also I deleted the migration files but `(1146, "Table 'subscribers.dashboard_subscribers' doesn't exist")` error is shown when I submitted the form. Should I make a table or ?? I didnot understand the error.

Comment: did you used makemigrations? you have use makemigrations and migrate again then the table will be created

Comment: Yes I used makemigrations first and then migrate. `No changes detected` is displayed when I use `python manage.py makemigrations`. `(1146, "Table 'subscribers.dashboard_subscribers' doesn't exist")` is still the error

Comment: sorry to disturb you but I need your help again.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using two databases, for saving entities you should specify which database to save by specifying

```
Subs.save(using='db2')
```

According to [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/multi-db/#selecting-a-database-for-save):

> If you don’t specify using, the save() method will save into the
>   default database allocated by the routers.

Comment: I think it worked but still the database has some problem. `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: dashboard_subscribers.billNumber` is shown when I try `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I just removed the unique=True and applied makemigrations and migrate but whenever I use python manage.py migrate, the error is the same

Comment: As suggested by @Exprator, I think you may need to drop the database and create again.

Comment: I dropped the database and created a new one named 'Subscribers'. `(1146, "Table 'subscribers.dashboard_subscribers' doesn't exist")` error is shown when I submitted the form. Should I make a table or ?? I didnot understand the error.

Comment: After creating the new database, you should run the migrations to create tables.